# Formulas with data ranges and hidden cells

Tags: excel, libreoffice-calc

I have a large collection of data, which is accordingly filtered to do analysis. However, I cannot seem to be using the right values when selecting data ranges which contain hidden cells/rows by the filter. The table below shows an example. If I wanted to calculate the average of column TIME `=AVERAGE(E12:E16)`, the range will include the hidden value, row 11 and 13 in this case.

[image]

Is there anything I could do to use formulas of the filtered data without including the hidden (filtered out) values? I could work with Excel and/or Calc.

Comment: Especially for such cases, Calc includes [**SUBTOTAL()**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060106.html?DbPAR=CALC&HID=SC_HID_FUNC_TEILERGEBNIS#bm_id3165644) and [**AGGREGATE()**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/func_aggregate.html?DbPAR=CALC&HID=SC_HID_FUNC_AGGREGATE#bm_id13660154375100) functions